# SQL - If one record has a specific value get only that one, if not get all

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've this query that returns multiple records, if one of the values in a column is equal to a number, I only want to have that specific record, if not I want to have all the records.

I've tried to use some sub queries to achieve it, but i'm not that good in SQL.

```
Select       
    Material_Number,
    Supplier_Number,
    CODE
from 
    w_supp_ds
    where 
     Material_Number = '111111'
```

for this Material_Number I have this output

```
111111  1015221     blank
111111  1071384     blank
```

which is fine!

But if I got an output like this:

```
222222  1074556     2
222222  1001297     blank
```

I only want the first record. So if one record contains numeric in column Code, I get that one, if not I want the two blanks. This way I can't use something like WHERE IsNumeric(Code)

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `not exists` condition:

```
select . . .
from w_supp_ds w
where Material_Number = '111111' or
      not exists (select 1 from w_supp_ds w2 where w2.Material_Number = '111111')
```

Comment: Thank for your feed back, but didn't worked, I got the exact same output.

Comment: @HoracioPires . . . I believe this accurately answers the question that you have asked:  "if one of the values in a column is equal to a number, I only want to have that specific record, if not I want to have all the records.".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `RANK` analytic function might help:

```
SQL> with w_supp_ds (material_number, supplier_number, code) as
  2    (select 111111, 1015221, null from dual union all
  3     select 111111, 1071384, null from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 222222, 1074556, 2    from dual union all
  6     select 222222, 1001297, null from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select material_number, supplier_number, code,
 10        rank() over (order by code desc nulls last) rn
 11     from w_supp_ds w
 12     where Material_Number = &par_mat_num
 13    )
 14  select material_number, supplier_number, code
 15  from temp
 16  where rn = 1;
Enter value for par_mat_num: 111111

MATERIAL_NUMBER SUPPLIER_NUMBER       CODE
--------------- --------------- ----------
         111111         1015221
         111111         1071384

SQL> /
Enter value for par_mat_num: 222222

MATERIAL_NUMBER SUPPLIER_NUMBER       CODE
--------------- --------------- ----------
         222222         1074556          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a CASE statement in the WHERE clause:

```
Select       
  Material_Number,
  Supplier_Number,
  CODE
from w_supp_ds
where 
  Material_Number = '??????'
  and coalesce(CODE, '0') = case 
    when exists (select 1 from w_supp_ds where Material_Number = '??????' and CODE is not null) then CODE
    else '0'
  end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e10ae6cb8ced0751a761f3eaf396196).
Results for `Material_Number = '111111'`:

```
> MATERIAL_NUMBER | SUPPLIER_NUMBER | CODE
> :-------------- | :-------------- | :---
> 111111          | 1015221         | null
> 111111          | 1071384         | null
```

Results for `Material_Number = '222222'`:

```
> MATERIAL_NUMBER | SUPPLIER_NUMBER | CODE
> :-------------- | :-------------- | :---
> 222222          | 1074556         | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    MATERIAL_NUMBER,
    SUPPLIER_NUMBER,
    CODE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MATERIAL_NUMBER,
            SUPPLIER_NUMBER,
            CODE,
            COUNT(CODE) OVER(
                PARTITION BY MATERIAL_NUMBER
            ) M
        FROM
            W_SUPP_DS
        WHERE
            MATERIAL_NUMBER = '111111' --222222
    )
WHERE
    M = 0
    OR ( CODE IS NOT NULL )
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1acf402839b1c69c40e1531a116c886b)

Cheers!!